# Beaglebone GPIO "RuntimeError: Failed to add edge detection"

Tags: beagleboneblack

I am getting "RuntimeError: Failed to add edge detection" when trying to run the following on a BeagleBone running Ubuntu 13.10

```
import Adafruit_BBIO.GPIO as GPIO
def onGPIOEvent(channel):
    print "event detected!"
GPIO.setup("P9_28", GPIO.IN)
GPIO.add_event_detect("P9_28", GPIO.RISING, callback=onGPIOEvent, bouncetime=300)
```

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured out the problem. I had to run this with sudo privilege..

Answer (score -1):

The pin P9_28 does NOT have a GPIO option to it. Try another pin such as P9_30 and see if you still get the same error.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, I re-read my previous answer and realized I left our the word 'NOT,' which then made my answer into a pointless statement.